# Extend plugin javascript file from another plugin

Tags: javascript, shopware

Is it possible in Shopware 6 to extend plugins with another plugin? I have plugin A from the shopware store, I need to change its functionality a bit, because it does not quite suit me. This plugin overrides core functionality of shopware - ListingPlugin from src / plugin / listing / listing.plugin. I need to get the js file from plugin A from my plugin B or from theme. I didn't find any information on this functionality from documentation

Comment: Can you share the code with us? Do you use Shopware 5 or 6?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/modify-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Sorry, this is a question about Shopware 6

Comment: No problem :) Here you can find the docs https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/extend-core-js-storefront-plugin

Comment: I need to extend the plugin from shopware store, not core plugin from storefront

Comment: Do you have a link? I can't help you without knowing which plugin you use.

Comment: I try to extend this plugin https://store.shopware.com/en/tanma37171171180/infinite-scrolling-for-shopware-6.html?number=Tanma37171171180

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the plugin like

```js
import ExtendPlugin from './plugin/youtPluignFolder/extend-plugin.plugin';

const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
PluginManager.override('OrgPlugin', ExtendPlugin);

...
```

After register the file you need to create the file. There you can extend or overwrite the function like

```
import OrgPlugin from '/app/custom/plugins/pluginName/path/to/plugin-file.plugin';

export default class ExtendPlugin extends OrgPlugin {
    init() {
        super.init();
    }

    // Function you want overwrite or extend
    function () {
      //    your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that. In this case, it isn't working. I created register for this plugin:

```
import TanmarInfiniteScrollingExtend from './infinite-scrolling-extend/infinite-scrolling.plugin';

const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;

PluginManager.override('TanmarInfiniteScrolling', TanmarInfiniteScrollingExtend, '[data-listing]');
```

And then created the file with this code:

```
import TanmarInfiniteScrolling from 'src/infinite-scrolling/infinite-scrolling.plugin';

export default class TanmarInfiniteScrollingExtend extends TanmarInfiniteScrolling {
    init() {
        super.init();
    }
    _tmisInit() {
        super._tmisInit();
        console.log('Hello world')

    }
}
```

But when I tried to build a storefront, I got the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ7Rt.png

Probably the reason for that is because the parent plugin extends Listing Plugin.

```
PluginManager.override('Listing', TanmarInfiniteScrolling, '[data-listing]');
```

But when I tried to override ListingPlugin, the parent plugin is completely overwritten.

This is a structure of the file in parent plugin:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dDXL.png

Comment: You can use absolute path like `/app/custom/plugins/plugin-name/...`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with relative paths like `../../../../../../../ExternalPluginName/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/externalplugin/externalplugin.plugin`